# Strange fseek()/fwrite() performance on MacOS

Tags: performance, macos, fwrite, performance-testing, fseek

I have problems with write performance of `fseek()`/`fwrite()` on my Mac. I'm operating on large files up to 4 GB of size, tests below were made with a rather small one with only 120 MB. My strategy is as follows:

- `fopen()` a new file on disk
- fill the file with zeroes (takes ~3 seconds)
- write small blocks of data to random positions (30.000 blocks, 4k each)

The whole procedure takes around 120 seconds.

The write strategy is bound to an image rotation algorithm (see my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358919/how-can-i-speed-up-rotating-a-huge-tiff-by-90-degrees)) and unless someone comes up with a faster solution for the rotation problem, I'm not able to change the strategy of using `fseek()` and then writing 4k or less to the file.

What I am observing is this: The first few thousand `fseek()`/`fwrite()` perform quite well, but the performance drops very fast, faster than you would expect from any system cache being filled up. The chart below shows `fwrite()`s per second vs time in seconds. As you see, after 7 seconds the `fseek()`/`fwrite()` rate reaches approx. 200 per second, still going down until it reaches 100 per second at the very end of the process.

[image: fwrite() per seconds vs time]

In the middle of the process (2 or 3 times), the OS decides to flush file contents to disk which I can see from my console output hanging a few seconds, during that time I have approx. 5 MB/s write on my disk (which isn't that much). After `fclose()` the system seems to write the whole file, I see 20 MB/s disk activity for a longer period of time.

If I use `fflush()` every 5.000 `fwrite()`s, the behaviour doesn't change at all. Putting in `fclose()`/`fopen()` to force flushing somehow speeds up the whole thing by approx. 10%.

I did profile the process (screenshot below) and you see, that virtually all time is spent inside `fwrite()` and `fseek()` which can be drilled down to `__write_nocancel()` for both of them.

[image: Profiling the write function]

**Completely absurd summary**

Imagine the case where my input data fits into my buffers completely and thus I'm able to write my rotated output data linearly without the need to split the write process into fragments. I still use `fseek()` to position the file pointer, just because the logic of the writing function behaves that way, but the file pointer in this case is set to the same position where it already was. One would expect no performance impact. **Wrong**.

What is absurd is, if I remove the calls to `fseek()` for that special case, my function finishes within **2.7 seconds** instead of 120 seconds.

Now, after a long foreword, the question is: Why does `fseek()` have such an impact on performance, even if I seek to the same position? How could I speed it up (by another strategy or other function calls, disabling caching if possible, memory mapped access, ...)?

For reference, here's my code (not tidied up, not optimized, containing lots of debug output):

```
-(bool)writeRotatedRaw:(TIFF*)tiff toFile:(NSString*)strFile
{
    if(!tiff) return NO;
    if(!strFile) return NO;

    NSLog(@"Starting to rotate '%@'...", strFile);

    FILE *f = fopen([strFile UTF8String], "w");
    if(!f)
    {
        NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Could not open '%@' for writing.", strFile];
        NSRunAlertPanel(@"Error", msg, @"OK", nil, nil);
        return NO;
    }

#define LINE_CACHE_SIZE (1024*1024*256)

    int h = [tiff iImageHeight];
    int w = [tiff iImageWidth];
    int iWordSize = [tiff iBitsPerSample]/8;
    int iBitsPerPixel = [tiff iBitsPerSample];
    int iLineSize = w*iWordSize;
    int iLinesInCache = LINE_CACHE_SIZE / iLineSize;
    int iLinesToGo = h, iLinesToRead;

    NSLog(@"Creating temporary file");
    double time = CACurrentMediaTime();
    double lastTime = time;
    unsigned char *dummy = calloc(iLineSize, 1);
    for(int i=0; i<h; i++) fwrite(dummy, 1, iLineSize, f);
    free(dummy);
    fclose(f);
    f = fopen([strFile UTF8String], "w");
    NSLog(@"Created temporary file (%.1f MB) in %.1f seconds", (float)iLineSize*(float)h/1024.0f/1024.0f, CACurrentMediaTime()-time);
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);

    lastTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
    time = CACurrentMediaTime();
    int y=0;
    unsigned char *ucRotatedPixels = malloc(iLinesInCache*iWordSize);
    unsigned short int *uRotatedPixels = (unsigned short int*)ucRotatedPixels;
    unsigned char *ucLineCache = malloc(w*iWordSize*iLinesInCache);
    unsigned short int *uLineCache = (unsigned short int*)ucLineCache;
    unsigned char *uc;
    unsigned int uSizeCounter=0, uMaxSize = iLineSize*h, numfwrites=0, lastwrites=0;
    while(iLinesToGo>0)
    {
        iLinesToRead = iLinesToGo;
        if(iLinesToRead>iLinesInCache) iLinesToRead = iLinesInCache;

        for(int i=0; i<iLinesToRead; i++)
        {
            // read as much lines as fit into buffer
            uc = [tiff getRawLine:y+i withBitsPerPixel:iBitsPerPixel];
            memcpy(ucLineCache+i*iLineSize, uc, iLineSize);
        }

        for(int x=0; x<w; x++)
        {
            if(iBitsPerPixel==8)
            {
                for(int i=0; i<iLinesToRead; i++)
                {
                    ucRotatedPixels[iLinesToRead-i-1] = ucLineCache[i*w+x];
                }
                fseek(f, w*x+(h-y-1), SEEK_SET);
                fwrite(ucRotatedPixels, 1, iLinesToRead, f);
                numfwrites++;
                uSizeCounter += iLinesToRead;
                if(CACurrentMediaTime()-lastTime>1.0)
                {
                    lastTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
                    NSLog(@"Progress: %.1f %%, x=%d, y=%d, iLinesToRead=%d\t%d", (float)uSizeCounter * 100.0f / (float)uMaxSize, x, y, iLinesToRead, numfwrites);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for(int i=0; i<iLinesToRead; i++)
                {
                    uRotatedPixels[iLinesToRead-i-1] = uLineCache[i*w+x];
                }
                fseek(f, (w*x+(h-y-1))*2, SEEK_SET);
                fwrite(uRotatedPixels, 2, iLinesToRead, f);
                uSizeCounter += iLinesToRead*2;
                if(CACurrentMediaTime()-lastTime>1.0)
                {
                    lastTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
                    NSLog(@"Progress: %.1f %%, x=%d, y=%d, iLinesToRead=%d\t%d", (float)uSizeCounter * 100.0f / (float)uMaxSize, x, y, iLinesToRead, numfwrites);
                }
            }
        }
        y += iLinesInCache;
        iLinesToGo -= iLinesToRead;
    }

    free(ucLineCache);
    free(ucRotatedPixels);
    fclose(f);

    NSLog(@"Finished, %.1f s", (CACurrentMediaTime()-time));

    return YES;
}
```

I'm a bit lost because I do not understand how the system "optimizes" my calls. Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Once the data no longer fits the file system cache, you are starting to measure the disk write perf.  And then, yes, fseek() tells you how fast the disk write head can move.  Which is *very* slow.  Don't know enough about OSX but in general a 64-bit OS and lots of RAM buys you a big cache.

Comment: Please read again my "Completely absurd summary": When I write out all my 30.000 blocks linearly without fseek, then the whole process takes below 3 seconds. If I fseek to the same position as the file pointer already is, the performance drops by a factor of almost 40. Don't tell me that the system tries to move the disk head in the latter variant since this behaviour starts after the first *few* megabytes and no cache could be that small (given the fact that I still have ~2 GB of free, unused RAM on that machine). And yes, my OSX is 64 bits and has 8 GB of RAM which is enough for the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to somehow close this question, I'll answer it myself and share my solution.

Although I wasn't able to improve the performance of the `fseek()` calls, I did implement a well performing workaround. The aim was to avoid `fseek()` at any cost. Because I need to write fragments of data to different positions of the target file but those fragments appear in equal distance and the gaps between those fragments will be filled with other fragments written somewhat later in the process, I splitted the writing into multiple files. I write to as many files as fragment streams are generated and then, in a last step, re-open all those temporary files, read them rotational and linearly write data blocks to the target file. The performance of this is good, reaching approx. 4 seconds for the example given above.